# UnboundLocalError: local variable "tries" referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming and throwing myself in the deep end.
Trying to write a simple number guessing game, still very rough, but I'm getting an error I'm not sure how to fix.

This is the code:

import random
    guessestaken= 0
    print "You've got to guess a random number between 1 and 20"

```
def main():
    guessestaken = 0
    number = random.randint(1,20)
    guess = 0
    while guess != number:

        print ("Take a guess")
        guess = input("Your guess: ")
        guess = int(guess)
        guessestaken = guessestaken + 1
        if tries is None:
            tries = 0
        tries = tries + 1



        if guess < number:
            print "Too low, try again"

        if guess > number:
            print "Too high"


        if guess is number:
            print "Well done, you guessed the number in ", guessestaken, "guesses."


#        if guess != number:

x = 1
while x is 1:
#    if tries is 3: break
    guessestaken = 0
    main()
```

And I'm getting this error after:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tries' referenced before assignment, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you must intialize tries, add  `tries=0` after `def main():`

Comment: Why first three lines are getting repeated ?

Comment: If I add `tries=0` aftef `def main():` then my counter would get reset each time.

Comment: Sorry first 3 lines aren't repeated in my code, must have pasted twice or something.

Comment: Please state more clearly what `tries` is trying to do. And if you spot a typo in your question (duplicate lines etc): fix it!

Comment: Edited code, sorry. `tries` is trying to count the amount of times the game is played, maybe I should have called it `gamesplayedsofar` I've kind of done what I've intended (see my "answer" on page"), but I haven't made it smooth or pretty yet.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check an undefined variable for `None`:

```
def main():
    while True:
        if tries is None:
            tries = 0
        tries = tries + 1
```

instead you should define it beforehand

```
def main():
    tries = 0

    while True:
        tries = tries + 1
```

You can check if a variable is defined using

```
try:
    tries
except NameError:
    tries = 0
```

but **I absolutely recommend against it**. There is always a way to make sure a variable is defined and code which is uncertain if a variable is defined is badly designed.

Comment: The code you've given is good for the `guessestaken` I was trying to count the amount of times the function had ran, I think I was doing it in the wrong place? I've set it under the while loop that runs the `main()` function now.

Comment: You can define `tries` to be a global variable (like `guessestaken`). It will then be defined and retain its value even if `main()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

With the following statement:

```
if tries is None:
    tries = 0
    tries = tries + 1
```

you are checking the value of a variable that doesn't exist. You can fix that by adding a value to `tries` at the beginning of the function, thus creating it. For example: `tries = 0`

Comment: I'm trying to count the amount of times the main() function has run, I don't think I made that clear. So if I put 'tries = 0' at the  start of the function this will reset it every time?

Answer (score 0):

I have done what I intended, not sure if it's a good way about it. I have added the tries in the while loop, to count how many times it goes through this loop.

```
    tries = 0               
x = 1
while x is 1:

    tries = tries + 1
    print tries
#    if tries is 3: break
    guessestaken = 0
    main()
```